# PSQL Dynamic Key value for json_agg

Tags: json, postgresql

I have this table structure:

[image]

I'm grouping every element into an array based on the name column:

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
  'id', id,
  'time', time,
  'version', version,
  'desc1', 'desc1',
  'desc2', 'desc2',
 ))
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name
```

which gives me this result:

```
[ { json_agg: [ [Object] ] }, { json_agg: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

how ever I want the `json_agg` key to be the same as the `name` column value.
like this:

```
[ { test1: [ [Object] ] }, { test2: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

How do I achieve this? Using an `AS name` doesn't work.

Comment: Please make one part of your example match the other part of your example.

Comment: `json_agg` is the column name of the resulting row(s). You cannot make that dynamic. And your desired output doesn't really make sense - aren't you rather looking for something like a single `{"test1": [{…}, {…}], "test2": [{…}]}` object?

Comment: It might help you understand what's going on when you look at the output of `SELECT name AS key, json_agg(json_build_obect(…)) AS values FROM my_table GROUP BY name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each grouping, you to build a new object using `name` and the aggregated array result in a subquery. Then aggregate the objects created in that subquery into a single array.

```sql
SELECT
  json_agg(elem) arr
FROM

(
SELECT
    json_build_object(
      name,
      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', id,
        'time', time,
        'version', version,
        'desc1', 'desc1',
        'desc2', 'desc2',
      ))
    ) elem

FROM
 my_table

GROUP BY
  name
) elem
```